# SVG styling in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to style SVG,  in order to export the from another location I transform SVG to TSX, I want component props changing with "FFF", when I hovering on Btn.

```
function Button() {
  const context = useContext(myContext);

  return (
    <Btn onClick={() => context.setNewPassword(context.generatedpassword)}>
      Generate
      <ArrowIcon fill="#24232C" />
    </Btn>
  );
}

/* Define your styling for the SVG component here */
const Btn = styled.button`
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.basic.green};
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.typography.fontSize.small};
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.basic.cardsBackgroundColor};
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 24px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: ${({ theme }) => theme.typography.fontWeight};

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: ${({ theme }) =>
      theme.colors.button.hoverBackgroundColor};
    border: solid 1px ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.button.hoverBorderColor};
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.button.hoverColor};
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your bundler / SVG transformer, you may be able to pass a `className` property directly to `ArrowIcon` like you'd do with any html element. Alternatively, you should be able to use the `svg` tag in a css selector

```
<ArrowIcon className="icon" />
```

```css
.btn {
  /* ...button styles */
  svg /* or .icon etc. */ { fill: #24232C; }
  
  &:hover {
    /* ...button styles on hover */
    svg { fill: #FFF; }
  }
}
```

Make sure your SVG file doesn't contain its own `fill` attributes that would override these css rules.